# Dynamic Schema Discovery is not done in case of Drill- Hive

Tags: apache-drill

I am using hive with drill.

*Storage Plugin* info:

```
{
  "type": "hive",
  "enabled": true,
  "configProps": {
    "hive.metastore.uris": "",
    "javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL": "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/metastore_hive",
    "javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName": "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
    "javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName": "root",
    "javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword": "root",
    "hive.metastore.warehouse.dir": "/user/hive/warehouse",
    "fs.default.name": "file:///",
    "hive.metastore.sasl.enabled": "false"
  }
}
```

It's working fine for querying and all.

**Then I wanted to check whether  it automatically discover newly created tables in hive or not.**

I started drill in embedded mode and used a particular database in hive using

```
use hive.testDB;
```

Here `testDB` is a database in Hive with tables `t1` & `t2`. Then I queried:

```
show tables;
```

It gave me table names

```
t1 
t2
```

I created a table `t3` in hive and again fired `show tables;` in Drill.
It's still showing  `t1 t2`. After 5-10 min I fired  `show tables;` again and it's showing `t1 t2 t3`.

I think it should show `t3` immediately after adding `t3` in hive.

> What can be reason for this behavior and how drill is handling it internally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked the same question on Drill's community & found it's solution:

Drill uses cache in its HiveMetaStoreClient, in order to reduce the
overhead to access HiveMetaStore. By default, the [cache TTL](https://github.com/apache/drill/blob/master/contrib/storage-hive/core/src/main/java/org/apache/drill/exec/store/hive/DrillHiveMetaStoreClient.java#L138) is 60 seconds.

There is a resolved issue on this. This issue is incorporated in Drill 1.5.  Cache TTL  can be made shorter by configuring hive storage plugin.

If you want to make the cache TTL shorter, you could configure hive
storage plugin.

**Sample hive plugin** (*with cache ttl 5 seconds*):

```
"configProps": {
  "hive.metastore.uris": "thrift://hive.ip.address.com:9083",
  ... // other setting, 

  "hive.metastore.cache-ttl-seconds": "5",
  "hive.metastore.cache-expire-after": "access"
}
```

Check more details [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DRILL-4161).